# Add attribute to Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: html, razor, attr, html.dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.Homeowner, new SelectList(
                    new List<Object>{ 
                    new { value = true , text = "Yes" },
                    new { value = false , text = "No"}
                }, "value", "text"),
               "--Select--"
```

Hey guys I am trying to add a 'required' at attribute to this DropDownListFor drop down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your model you should have something like:

```
[Required]
public virtual bool? Homeowner { get; set; }
```

Set the attribute as nullable to differentiate between false and not set, then use the `[Required]` parameter to ensure that the value is set on the page.